# append jquery objects why wont this work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write my jquery in a more 
object orientated way but I is not working , 
can you please help?  the result I get 
is object object

http://jsfiddle.net/Nrebv/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var divA = $('<div>', { class: 'divA' });
        var btn = $('<span>', { text: 'MYspanBTN' });

        btn.click(function(){

            alert('test');

        });


        var divResult = $('<div>', { html: divA + btn });





        $('#main').append(divResult);

});
```

Comment: It's unclear to me how this is done in "...a more object orientated way..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var divResult = $('<div>', { html: divA + btn });
```

with this:

```
var divResult = $('<div>').append(divA, btn);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrebv/1/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. <s>`class` is a reserved word, so to use it as a property name in an object initializer, you must put it in quotes (single or double, either is fine).</s> Actually, that's not true. In the specific place you've used it, it's actually okay. I wouldn't recommend it, though. Put it in either single or double quotes: `var divA = $('<div>', { 'class': 'divA' });`
2. Your `html: divA + btn` is trying to combine two object instances. If your goal is to combine their HTML, then `html: divA.html() + btn.html()`. If your goal is to make `divResult` a set with both of those elements, don't use `html` at all, do this:

   ```
   var divResult = divA.add(btn);
   ```

   ...which creates a new jQuery set with the contents of both of those sets (in your case, each of them only contains one element, so `divResult` will end up containing two).

Answer (score 0):

maybe is because of `class` which is reserved keyword in javascript

[Reserved Words - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

And about concatenating, it is wrong, so use:

```
var divResult = $('<div>').append(divA, btn);
```

instead of

```
    var divResult = $('<div>', { html: divA + btn });
```

Comment: *"maybe is because of class which is reserved keyword in javascript"* It's true that `class` is a reserved word, but in the *specific* place the OP used it, it's actually allowed. The property name portion of a property initializer is just required to be an *IdentifierName*, not an *Identifier* (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5). Surprising, but true.